# Stripe credit card processing error occurring all of a sudden

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I am getting this error on the browser when processing credit card using stripe.

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection.
 Stripe.utils.r.serialize
 Stripe.utils.r.serialize
 Stripe.utils.r.serialize
 Stripe.utils.r.serialize
 Stripe.ajaxJSONP
 e.request
 t.create
 n.createToken
Acpremium.Views.FyUpgradeCCCaptureView.FyUpgradeCCCaptureView.onPaymentSubmit
p.event.dispatch
g.handle.h
```

My code uses Backbone & CoffeeScript to invoke Stripe. My code (shown below) was functioning & processing payments until 6th November, 2014. Since then, the error above has started happening.

Stripe invocation in my code:

```
   onPaymentSubmit: (event) =>
    event.preventDefault()
    $("*").addClass("busy")

    paymentForm = @$('#payment-form')
    paymentForm.find('button').prop('disabled', true)
    Stripe.card.createToken paymentForm, @stripeResponseHandler
    false
```

If I change the code

```
paymentForm = @$('#payment-form')
```

to

```
   paymentForm = $('#payment-form')
```

the processing goes through. Is there any explanation for this?

An earlier stackoverflow question [How to fit Stripe into Backbone View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156946/how-to-fit-stripe-into-backbone-view)
indicates @$ is the right way to go and @$ was working for me as well until recently.

Has anyone else experienced this issue on Stripe?

Comment: What changed in your code around November 6?

Comment: Nothing at all. The code has been the same for 4 months. That is what is surprising me. The error is thrown from deep down in stripe.js. Stripe support says no one else has reported a similar issue.

Comment: What does the form's HTML look like? The error message suggests that an `<input type="hidden">` is triggering the problem. Have any Backbone, Underscore, jQuery, ... upgrades happened?

Comment: The input element is <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"> in my payment-form. This line has been there for last 4 months. No version change of libraries from my end. Not sure if stripe.js internally relies on any Backbone, Underscor library and there is a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

If `onPaymentSubmit` is a method in your class, make sure that your Class has a proper `el` element that wraps your `#payment-form` element.

Your HTML, CoffeeScript structure should look like this :

```
<div class='payment'>
    <form id='payment-form'>...</form>
</div>
```

And CS :

```
class Payment extend Backbone.View

   el: ".payment"  // Here .payment is parent element to #payment-form

   ...

   onPaymentSubmit: => ...
```

When you lookup an element with `@$` it starts looking inside your View's `el` property. So basically in this case it would look like :

```
   @$("#payment-form") === $(".payment #payment-form")
```

My buest guess is that your `#payment-form` is outside the scope of your Backbone View

Comment: My payment-form is not an immediate child of el, but a grandchild in the node hierarchy.  Any nested child should still be in the scope, right?

Comment: Yes, any nested child should be in the scope. Anyway the only difference between `@$("..` and `$("..` is that it looks in the scope of your view. On initialization try `console.log(@$("#payment-form"))` to make sure your payment-form is inside the scope of your view.

Comment: Yes, I can see both $('#payment-form') and @$('payment-form') are in scope - meaning both of these refer to the same form with data values. The only difference I see is the value of a "context" object. One of these is "document" while the other has a nil value for it.